# Orchard Workflows - keep format of text in textarea

Tags: orchardcms

I have a workflow that sends an email when a form is submitted that contains a textarea.

My problem is that the formatting of the content entered into the textarea is lost (e.g. carriage returns / paragraphs) when the email is sent.

Is there a way to maintain the content exactly as the user entered it? At present I am using this to output the content in the Email activity:

```
<p>Message:<br/>
{Request.Form:Message}</p>
```

It is running Orchard 1.10.2. Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

If you use dynamic forms this syntax will work:

```
FormSubmission.Field:Message.LineEncode
```

If it is your own form I'm afraid it looks like it is a bug in Orchard where the chained value of a Request.Form is actually retrieving the named query string parameter instead. To sort this you will have to edit this file of the source: `Orchard.Tokens.Providers.RequestTokens`.

Add a new method:

```
private static Tuple<string, string> FilterChainParam(string token, string tokenType) {
    if(token.StartsWith(tokenType, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
        return FilterChainParam(token);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Then replace this line in the `Evaluate` method:

```
.Chain(FilterChainParam, "Text", (token, request) => request.QueryString.Get(token))
```

with these lines:

```
.Chain((token) => FilterChainParam(token, "QueryString"), "Text", (token, request) => request.QueryString.Get(token))
.Chain((token) => FilterChainParam(token, "Form"), "Text", (token, request) => request.Form.Get(token))
.Chain((token) => FilterChainParam(token, "Route"), "Text", (token, request) => GetRouteValue(token, request))
```

Not particularly pretty but it works. You can now use as below (**note** the parentheses around your form field)

**ORIGINAL**

Your form will come through with just new lines (\n) which the email client will ignore. You'll need to replace them with line breaks. Fortunately someone thought of this and there is a token for that in Orchard: `LineEncode`. Change your email activity to:

```
<p>Message:<br/>
{Request.Form:(Message).LineEncode}</p>
```

Comment: Thanks @Hazza, but when I try that I get nothing at all in the email. Do I need to enable Token Html / Element Tokens modules or something?

Comment: What version of Orchard are you using? Do you see the `LineEncode` token in the token drop down? It should be under text tokens

Comment: Are you using dynamic forms? You can then use this syntax: `FormSubmission.Field:Message.LineEncode`

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I'm using Dynamic Forms, so 'FormSubmission.Field:Message.LineEncode' worked - didn't realise I could do that, though great to have an alternative when I'm not. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, Orchard always has too many ways to do the same thing haha